# Google API Authentication from Web site

Tags: c#, authentication, google-api

I need to access a Google Spreadsheet from my web application.  This is a membership application that writes member info to the google spreadsheet.
When I run the code locally, the code below works.

```
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService(spreadsheetName);
service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

However, when I am running the web application on the server, the authentication fails.

```
Google.GData.Client.InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
at Google.GData.Client.Utilities.QueryClientLoginToken(GDataCredentials gc, String     serviceName, String applicationName, Boolean fUseKeepAlive, IWebProxy proxyServer, Uri clientLoginHandler)
at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.QueryAuthToken(GDataCredentials gc)
at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.EnsureCredentials()
at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.EnsureWebRequest()
at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.EnsureWebRequest()
at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(Uri queryUri, DateTime ifModifiedSince, String etag, Int64& contentLength)
at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery)
```

I also got this email from google:

```
Hi xxxxxx, 

Someone recently used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account 
xxxx@gmail.com. This person was using an application such as an email client 
or mobile device. 

We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access 
your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt:
```

I know the credentials are correct because they work when testing locally.

I see a lot of mention of OAuth for authentication.  The problem is I don't want to use the user's authentication.  Only my web app should be allowed to write to the spreadsheet, using the credentials I've supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the following URL, clicked on the button, and everything works now.  Really strange that this step is required.

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha